# Creating dynamic buttons on codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to make it so when i click a button another is created, and you can do this as many times as you want too. But I haven't been able to find a way to make it work, any ideas? I have tried creating a for loop but that just ends up overwriting the other buttons and deleting the tags.

Comment: post your code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Form f = new Form(BoxLayout.y());
f.add(createButton("Click Me"));
f.show();
```

Then the method `createButton()`:

```
private Button createButton(String title) {
    Button b = new Button(title);
    b.addActionListener(e -> {
       Container c = b.getParent();
       c.add(createButton(title));
       c.revalidate();
    });
    return b;
}
```

I'm guessing the thing you missed is the call to `revalidate()` which must be invoked when you change a `Form` after it was already shown. Notice the first addition occurs before the form is shown and doesn't invoke `revalidate()`.

Comment: Happy to help. BTW to get points in stack overflow which help you with permissions around the site you can accept correct answers by clicking the checkbox next to the answer and possibly upvoting it. This indicates the issue is resolved

Comment: Thanks for explaining that to me, i am fairly new to this